# Spring Kafka, manual commiting in different threads

Tags: java, concurrency, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Good day collegues. I am using Spring Kafka 2.2.5
I have a listener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.execution-task-topic}", containerFactory = "executionTaskObjectContainerFactory")
public void protocolEventsHandle(ExecutionTask executionTask,
    Acknowledgment acknowledgment,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) long offset) {

    ResponseEntity < String > stringResponseEntity = airflowRestRunner.startDag(executionTask);
    JSONObject body = new JSONObject(stringResponseEntity.getBody());
    String message = body.getString("message");
    String runId = messageParser.getRunId(message);
    ExecutionTaskMessageInfo messageInfo = new ExecutionTaskMessageInfo(offset, partition, false, acknowledgment);
    kafkaAcknowledgeObject.putMessageInfo(messageInfo, partition);

    this.executorService.submit(kafkaAlertProducer.produceMessageAfterTaskSuccess(runId, executionTask, messageInfo));

}
```

I do some operations and if they are succes i use Acknowledge interface to commit offset.

I have a problem.
While calculations are taking place in the created thread, the listener reads the message from the same offset again. Because of this, when i try to confirm the offset, the application crashes.

What the best practise to work with Kafka in concurency?
I could get up to 10 messages in parallel and i need commit them only after calculations.

**UPDATE1**

I store all my messages from kafka in:
key - partion number
value - special model Class that contains reference to needed Acknowledge

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class KafkaAcknowledgeObject < T extends Comparable > {

    protected ConcurrentHashMap < Integer,
    TreeSet < T >> hashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap < > ();

    public abstract void doAck();

    public void putMessageInfo(T message, int partition) {
        if (hashMap.containsKey(partition)) {
            hashMap.get(partition).add(message);
        } else {
            TreeSet < T > messageInfos = new TreeSet < > ();
            messageInfos.add(message);
            hashMap.put(partition, messageInfos);
        }
    }

}
```

After calculations i call `doAck()`, for example

```
@Override
public void doAck() {
    for (TreeSet < ExecutionTaskMessageInfo > messageInfoTreeSet: super.hashMap.values()) {
        checkHandledOffsets(messageInfoTreeSet);
    }
}

private void checkHandledOffsets(TreeSet < ExecutionTaskMessageInfo > messageInfoTreeSet) {
    ExecutionTaskMessageInfo first = getFirstMessageInfo(messageInfoTreeSet);
    if (first.isCompleted()) {
        first.getAcknowledgment().acknowledge();
        messageInfoTreeSet.remove(first);
        checkHandledOffsets(messageInfoTreeSet);
    }

    return;
}

private ExecutionTaskMessageInfo getFirstMessageInfo(TreeSet < ExecutionTaskMessageInfo > messageInfoTreeSet) {
    Iterator < ExecutionTaskMessageInfo > iterator = messageInfoTreeSet.iterator();

    return iterator.next();
}
```

Comment: "Crashes" is not enough information; add the actual error, stack trace etc. Also show the code that's actually calling `acknowledge()`. The records should not be redelivered unless a rebalance occurs,

Comment: @GaryRussell, thank you for answer. I aded some info. I couldn't catch an Exeception, but i am trying to do it right.
The main problem that after starting calculation in it own thread method with KafkaListener get the similiar message once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing should be fine; I just tested a similar arrangement and it works fine for me...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So56190029Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So56190029Application.class, args);
    }

    private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

    @KafkaListener(id = "so56190029", topics = "so56190029")
    public void listen(String in, Acknowledgment ack) {
        this.exec.execute(runner(in, ack));
    }

    private Runnable runner(String payload, Acknowledgment ack) {
        return () -> {
            System.out.println(payload);
            if (this.count.incrementAndGet() % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println("acking");
                ack.acknowledge();
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<?, String> template) {
        return args -> IntStream.range(0, 6).forEach(i -> template.send("so56190029", "foo" + i));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(Level.INFO);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.records=3
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=MANUAL
```

and

```
foo0
foo1
foo2
acking
foo3
foo4
foo5
acking
2019-05-17 14:46:28.790  INFO 62429 --- [o56190029-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer 
    : Committing: {so56190029-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=36, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}
```

Comment: Stupid question, but could it be because of i hold debug breakpoints too long?

Comment: That could cause a rebalance if you hold up a listener for 5 minutes (max.poll.interval.ms). I see you are using 2.2.5 so you don't have a pre-KIP-62 client (which would rebalance much quicker).

Comment: So, if i got correctly then my calculation should be ended faster then 5 min?
For example if i have only one message in partition/

Comment: No; since you are handing off to another thread, you don't need to worry about that. The `@KafkaListener` method must take no longer than `max.poll.interval.ms / max.poll.records`. i.e. you must process all records from the poll within `max.poll.interval.ms`. Turning on DEBUG logging should help you figure out what's going on.